# Перестал работать yield return new WaitForSeconds (unity3d)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Во всей игре внезапно перестал работать `yield return new WaitForSeconds`

```
public IEnumerator corTimer() {
        while (inTime > 0) {
            inTime--;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
        startNovel();
}
```

Первый раз срабатывает и больше в цикл не возвращается, если сделать `yield return null;` то все нормально цикл проходиться. Дебажил - никакого null не выскакивает. И это по всей игре, помогите пожалуйста, хотя бы приблизительно что это может быть, я без понятия.

Comment: а после первого срабатывания вы присваиваете переменной inTime новое значение ?

Comment: Ну это глобальная переменная я ее нигде больше не использую вроде она у меня равна 3 потом inTime-- 2 так и остаеться

Comment: вы не могли где то выставить Time.timeScale = 0 ?

Comment: Большое спасибо - это заработало. Действительно, почему то в Edit/ProjectSettings/Time Time Scale был 0. Я туда не лазил, не знаю почему он изменился. Это решение проблемы. Можно писать в ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась в Time.timeScale = 0